# Firestore database design: teams vs games vs players

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have zero Firestore experience and am coming from a SQL background. I did an app using SQL that seemed to work well but I'm confused in how to replicate the design in Firestore's NoSQL approach.

Say I have a team that has many games. And that same team has many players. And each game has many players.

Now say I wanted to store the stats for each player in each game as well as cumulative stats for each player.

In SQL, I would store the stats in separate tables: a `gameResults` table (stats for each individual game) and add each game's stats to a `players` table (cumulative stats).

In Firestore, how would I achieve the same thing in an efficient way?

I was thinking a `teams` root collection with individual teams as documents, then two sibling subcollections for each team: `games` and `players` (the latter for cumulative player stats). Each `games` document (individual game) would have another subcollection, also called `players`, which would have the stats for that particular game for each player. I would copy the game stats for each player into the cumulative stats `players` subcollection. Not sure if this was an inefficient/inappropriate setup in Firestore. If so, what's the best way to model this?

Comment: The best way is avoid using the subcollection,if it is  possible. Beause querying with subcollection is difficult as compared to the root collection

Answer (score 0):

i think you only need four root collections,

1)teams

2)players

3)games

4)player_status

Comment: why? i haven't read anywhere the querying with subcollections is difficult...?

Comment: as compared to the root collection

Answer (score 0):

#### Firestore:

Firestore is a NoSQL database and @pepe is right. For best practice is better for you to have different root collections for every type of information that you would like to store. However, I am posting this answer as well to elaborate more on what exactly your database will look like an how the data will be stored there.

**How Firestore works:**

Firestore has **Collections**, **Documents**, **Fields**.

For example if you would like to store contact information, you can do so like:

**Collection:** "contacts" > **Document:** "UNIQUE_ID" > Fields: **Name:**   STRING, **Sname:**  STRING, **Mobile:** NUMBER

**The data is going to be saved like this:**

```
contacts > UNIQUE_ID_01 > Name:   Andrew
                          Sname:  Williams
                          Mobile: 99741258

           UNIQUE_ID_02 > Name:   Margaret
                          Sname:  Smith
                          Mobile: 99451236
```

As you can see, each contact has its own UNIQUE ID which is either auto generated when you create the document or you can generate it using API. Then each document is all the information that you would like to store about this contact.

Now this will help you to make relations in other collections where you don't want to store the same information again and just save the reference UNIQUE ID. For example you are doing a collection for company and which contacts work there. Instead of having a field in the company's sub-document that will have again name, sname, mobile etc. you just store all the unique IDs of each contact in a singe array field. Then if you would like to find the contact's information you do new queries for each document ID and just get the data you want.

#### Architectural design:

First of all it is recommended to write down the data that you are about to store and specify the relationship between them:

**Type:**

- Teams
- Games
- Players

**You want to update:**

- Status of each player for each game
- Status for each player based on all games he played

Now the Type of information you specified that you want to save is going to be your root collections.

#### How Firestore is going to look:

**Collection:** "Teams" > **Document:** "UNIQUE_TEAM_ID" > Fields: **Title:** STRING, **Players:**  ARRAY, **Team_stats**: NUMBER

**Collection:** "Games" > **Document:** "UNIQUE_GAME_ID" > Fields: **Title:** STRING, **Date:**  TIMESTAMP, **Players**: ARRAY, **Teams**: ARRAY

**Collection:** "Players" > **Document:** "UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID" > Fields: **Name:** STRING, **Surname:**  STRING, **Mobile**: NUMBER, **Stats_all_games**: NUMBER

#### How data is going to look in Firestore:

```
Players > UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_01 > Name:            Andrew 
                                Surname:         Williams
                                Mobile:          99784512
                                Stats_all_games: 75.0

          UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_02 > Name:            Margaret
                                Surname:         Smith
                                Mobile:          99451236
                                Stats_all_games: 75.0
Teams > UNIQUE_TEAM_ID_01 > Title:      Awesome Team
                            Players:    [UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_01, UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_02]
                            Team_stats: 95.0
        UNIQUE_TEAM_ID_02 > Title:      Another Awesome Team
                            Players:    [UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_03, UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_04]
                            Team_stats: 46.0

Games > UNIQUE_GAME_ID_01 > Title:   Team 1 vs Team 2
                            Date:    1576593460
                            Teams:   [UNIQUE_TEAM_ID_01, UNIQUE_TEAM_ID_02]
                            Players: [UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_01, UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_02 ...]

        UNIQUE_GAME_ID_01 > Title:   Team 3 vs Team 4
                            Date:    1576593460
                            Teams:   [UNIQUE_TEAM_ID_03, UNIQUE_TEAM_ID_04]
                            Players: [UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_15, UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_16 ...]
```

So the idea is of having the unique ids stored in arrays, that so when you query per status of the team for example, you will only get the data about the team and the necessary data to create a new query if needed.

For example you can query to see all the Games after date 1576593460. When the data is loaded as snapshot, if you would like to get the information of the teams you have the IDs and you can query again with those IDs to get the info of the teams. If also needed to see the players you have all the player ids within the retrieved data as well so you can query per person and get individual data of each player.

This is how more or less I would have implemented this. Definitely there are many other options and maybe even better practices of how to use Firestore. However, if you like this approach and understand it better, then you can implement it with your logic

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to have answered the question. However, the steps to query the data can be improved if you want to also have a python back end. Please see the `MeetingSession` example in the [framework](https://github.com/billyrrr/flask-boiler) that I am currently developing. If you use `flask-boiler`, the backend would handle the process of

> you can query to see all the Games after date 1576593460. When the data is loaded as snapshot, if you would like to get the information of the teams you have the IDs and you can query again with those IDs to get the info of the teams. If also needed to see the players you have all the player ids within the retrieved data as well so you can query per person and get individual data of each player.

and stores the result in a single `document` that is normalized. The front end just have to access the document `aggregated_game_id_01`. This results in lower latency in your use cases, but has other drawbacks such as storing unnecessary data.

So, in addition to the root collections mentioned in the other answer, you can generate these with `flask-boiler`

```
TeamsView > UNIQUE_TEAM_ID_01 > Title:      Awesome Team
                            Players:    {UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_01: {
                                              Name:            Andrew 
                                              Surname:         Williams
                                              Mobile:          99784512
                                              Stats_all_games: 75.0}
                                         UNIQUE_PLAYER_ID_02: {
                                              Name:            Margaret
                                              Surname:         Smith
                                              Mobile:          99451236
                                              Stats_all_games: 75.0}
                                              }
                            Team_stats: 95.0
```

Hope that this offers you an additional option to query the data. Let me know if you want more explanation. Thanks.